# Google Map KML layer placemark click event return ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

Attaching listener to KML layer:

```
var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://sites.google.com/site/kmlprototypes/kmls/temp.kml?dc_=' + Math.random(),
{suppressInfoWindows:true,preserveViewport:true});

layer.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function (obj) {
    alert(obj.featureData.id);
});
```

KML file is valid (checked by validation api), you may find it [here](http://sites.google.com/site/kmlprototypes/kmls/temp.kml). Each placemark in XML has id attribute like:

```
<Placemark id="46">
  <Style>
    <IconStyle>
      <Icon>
        <href>
          <![CDATA[http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,EAF7FE02&chxt=y&chbh=a,4,4&chs=48x48&cht=bvg&chco=FF0000,0000FF&chds=20,9048.00,0,9048.00&chd=t:8149.00|9048.00]]>
        </href>
      </Icon>
    </IconStyle>
  </Style>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>30.49566650390625,50.721378326416016</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

When clicking on a placemark in google map object returns right id, but sometimes about 50% of the time `obj.featuredData.id` is `null` (`ZERO_RESULTS` status is in `status` field). I have tried different sets of data (form 100 points to 1000), but it doesn't help. Also I've tried different precisions for lat, lng.

Comment: Do only the [custom markers (the "charts")](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fsites.google.com%2Fsite%2Fkmlprototypes%2Fkmls%2Ftemp.kml&hl=en&gl=us&t=m&z=9&iwloc=lyrftr:kml:cu4G8yGAGMgyJQA_oDPu6YymLEiMB,ga181ff8803d8d1b7_886,50.483726,30.091553,0,-32) exhibit the problem?

Comment: Looks like your KML contains too many custom markers.  [Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=50.501460&lng=30.404131&zoom=13&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmlprototypes_temp_kml.xml) it is rendered using geoxml3 (takes a while to render). If you hide those markers (click the hide button), then display the KmlLayer, you see a combination of default blue markers and custom markers.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably hit one the limits listed on that page: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport?hl=en

Maximum 1000 features per file could be the one that is bothering you.