# Including interactive HTML5 in KML icons

Tags: javascript, html, charts, kml

I'm wondering if its possible to include HTML5 tags in a KML Icon, essentially, I'd like to include these interactive pie charts above specific areas on my map: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Is This possible?

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmlprototypes_temp_kml.xml) from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775801/google-map-kml-layer-placemark-click-event-return-zero-results) uses chart icons from http://chart.apis.google.com/, so I would think yours would work.  There are issues when that many custom icons are rendered using KmlLayer (you didn't indicate how many of these you needed to render).  I don't think this uses HTML5 though.